# spree footer image path ошибка

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, spree

Добрый день. Начал использовать spree,к горю или к сожалению... Скорее всего второе.

Проблема в том, что мои изображения не отображаются корректно, а именно во вьюхах разных контроллеров.

Вот примеры моих вьюх:

## spree/layouts/spree_application.html.erb

```
<%= render partial: 'spree/shared/footer' %>
```

## spree/shared/_footer.html.erb

```
<li><img src="vm.png" alt=""></li>
```

Изображения лежат в appname/public, и корректно отображается лишь на главной странице, на других пропадают изображения, хотя это же футер из application.

2) Судя по гайду с офф сайта изображения должны находиться в других папках, куда я их не вставлял, какие пути не указывал в web inspector, все равно не отображается :(

Помогите пожалуйста

p.s в другом вопросе на стаке увидел вот такое :

"Найдите файл spree/backend/config/routes.rb . В конце этого файла есть строка"  Файл этот есть на гитхабе, а вот где он расположен на компьютере...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> и корректно отображается лишь на главной странице, на других пропадают изображения

Не кажется странным? Выходит, загружаемость или незагружаемость изображения зависит от текущей страницы? Значит ли это, что картинка указана **относительным путём**?

Хм... а ведь так и есть:

```
<img src="vm.png" alt="">
```

Чтобы искать всегда именно в корне сайта, нужно начинать путь с `/`, чтобы URL был относительным для **сайта**, но не для **страницы** (т. е. имел тот же источник, но не путь):

```
<img src="/vm.png" alt="">
```

---

*Относительные URL описываются [RFC 1808](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1808). Там попадаются строгие технические описания, но с объяснениями рядом с ними стоит ознакомиться.*

Comment: Просто царь программирования. Склоняюсь перед Вашей мощью. :)